# Add COM 32 to VB.NET

Tags: .net, com, dll, dllimport

How can I add a COM DLL to A VB.NET project?

Comment: DllRegisterServer entry point was not found -

Comment: Well in that case your question is "how do I make and install a COM component?" not "how do I use it from VB.NET?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: use "Add Reference" in Solution Explorer.

You can add COM compontents in there and use interop to access them.

Comment: I cant register com dll for use